# Connection to Pphmyadmin failed with " hp_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed"

Tags: php, mysql

So situation is like this: I had DB that worked and still works with Phpmyadmin (SQL). I made new Database and made sure I put right connection information in PHP script which should connect to it. This very weird error occurs in the browser, when ever I try to connect to it.

```
Connection failed: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Temporary failure in name resolution
```

I have to point out that if I try to connect to the other DB it works just fine.

Can anybody point me out into right direction what this might be ? If you need PHP script let me know.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The error says you can't resolve the host name, so could be related to issue in DNS or the host is unreachable etc. . You can try to ping your host where the db is to check if it is up, or use the ip in the db connection parameters to avoid the DNS resolution.